# Run JUnit in IntelliJ while ignoring compilation error in an unrelated class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When running a JUnit test case in IntelliJ it opens up the Make console and shows complication errors in an unrelated class.

1. Can I run the test case ignoring these errors?
2. Is there a way to make it not compile the entire project when running the test cases but only those class files required by the test case?

Comment: @NimChimpsky Another reason might be if you have several tests with compilation errors and would prefer to fix them in one class and ensure that it passes before moving on to the next one. While "just fix the compiler issues" is generally good advice, there are some times where this sort of workflow is preferred.

Comment: @NimChimpsky Yes, that sounds like a great Idea! I just have to revert 1000 commits! Good job.

Comment: "fix the compiler issues" before running JUnit tests only makes sense to people coding for 2nd-semester exams.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can disable the Make before Run.

(The following is written for IntelliJ 14, different versions might have slightly different layouts, but as far as I can remember these options have been the same for a while)

For a single test

- Go to "Run" - "Edit Configurations..."
- Select the configuration of your test case
- In the tab named "Configuration" there is a List "Before Launch" with one entry "Make". Remove that entry.
- Confirm with "OK"

For all tests:

If you want to remove this by default for all new test configurations (which might not be a terribly good idea, since then you got to allways build manually when running tests)

- Go to "Run" - "Edit Configurations..."
- Select "Defaults" in the Tree
- Select your Testframework (Junit or TestNG most probably)
- In the tab named "Configuration" there is a List "Before Launch" with one entry "Make". Remove that entry.
- Confirm with "OK"

Comment: This works. But I think instead of removing "Make" selecting "Make no error check" would be more useful so that the classes that the test depends on get recompiled.

Comment: Now changed to "Build" and "Build no error check" in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)

Comment: I am attempting the "build no error check" solution but am finding with it selected Intellij is not even compiling the [net new] test. I get a no class def found on the JUnit itself. This is a new junit in the face of a large refactor effort. Anyone else?

Comment: In IntelliJ 2021.2 there's no "Configuration" tab for JUnit.

Comment: @BetaRide were you able to find a solution that works on IntelliJ 2021.2?

Comment: For a current Intellij there is is a Menu "Modify Options" where you set Do not build before run