# Configuration required to run JUnit in IntelliJ Idea while ignoring compilation error in an unrelated class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit4

I have been facing issues since very long about running the JUnit in IntelliJ Idea, since there are compilation issue here and there due to some missing jar, or dependency which I should not be bothering about while writing a Junit or testing an existing one.

I have been working with the follwing version of IntelliJ

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-222.4554.10, built on March 15, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+7-b469.82 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

I have already tried the existing proposed solution but it didn't worked for me [Run JUnit in IntelliJ while ignoring compilation error in an unrelated class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535628/run-junit-in-intellij-while-ignoring-compilation-error-in-an-unrelated-class)

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your run/debug configuration including Before launch  section. Try to select `Build, no error check` instead of `Build` Update the IDE to the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: I have done that, apart from that I have tried excluding other modules (by excluding them through setting) of the current project, and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from adding Before launch: "Build, no error check" in the test configuration, just exclude the modules which you want to avoid for compilation while executing your Junit tests

You can navigate it through Files > Setting > Build, execution, Deployment > Compiler > Excludes and just add the modules you want to exclude

But make sure, you re-compile the test file everytime after you make the changes, otherwise it won't run with the latest changes